# Update Price on Products

Tags: magento-1.8

I have many products, and I want to update product's price but only specific products with the following attribute:wheels, tires by 12% and 14%.How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to increase price then it cannot be possible.**

If you want to ***discount on basic of attribute*** then use magento [Catalog price rules.](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html).

For your requirment,you need to create two different Catalog Price rules one for 14% and other for 12%.

Checkout how to [setup catalog rules follow the link](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/)

Comment: Any idea how to increase it? Example if the current price is 120, I want to increase it to add 5 , thus it should show 125